# Download files using url in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, next.js

I have multiple url's, pointing to pdf's in google drive, and docs. I want to be able to download them just by using the url string automatically with Javascript code, instead of manually going to the link and downloading them.

I have searched a lot of other answers on stackoverflow, few suggest creating an anchor tag in document body, but I am doing everything on backend not creating an index.html

edit: I am using next where for an api end point I am getting post requests, each which contains URL for a file which I have to download.

This is how I expect my POST request to come:

[image]

I want to be able to do something like this (in nextjs):

```
export default async function handler (req, res) {
    if(req.method === "POST") {
       let path = "./downloads/file"
       await download(req.body.url, path)
    }
}
```

Is the `download` function possible, if so please help me with the implementation or provide any helpful packages to do the same.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? You tagged this [tag:fetch] (which is marked DO NOT USE so I guess you meant [tag:fetch-api]; how are you using it? Provide a [mcve]. What problem are you having? Is the problem with making the request or turning the response into a download?

Comment: "but I am doing everything on backend not creating an index.html" — does that mean you are doing this in Node.js and no web browser is involved? You just want to download the file to the same computer as the Node.js program is running on?

Comment: if you are doing everything on backend why don't use something like curl and that's all? Because it seems quite impossible using web api on browser.. using fetch you can't save the result, using the download attribute and triggering its click will have mixed result depending on many factors, using window.open will be hostage of the mime type and multiple further obstacles. Since you were not clear about the console where you are going to interface with this logic.. just use a script calling curl or wget and download those resources in the easiest way possible

Comment: @Quentin yes No browser is involved, I am using next where for an api end point I am getting post requests, each which contains URL for a file which I have to download

Comment: Well, Next.js is a React based framework. So you want the browser (running a React app) to make a request to the API on the server (running Next.js) and then that API needs to get a URL and make an HTTP request from the Next.js server (and not from the browser) to that URL, and then save the file on the server's hard disk but **not** pass the file back to the browser for downloading?

Comment: I am coding the api part independently, just assume that I am using express standalone

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the download attribute on the anchor https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

You may be doing everything back-end - but you're asking about a front-end operation such as a request to download a document.

Comment: That won't work. The question says the URLs point to Google Drive and Google Docs. The `download` attribute doesn't work cross-origin.

Comment: They also said "I have searched a lot of other answers on stackoverflow, few suggest creating an anchor tag in document body, but I am doing everything on backend not creating an index.html" which explicitly rules out your suggestion.